# First time cider is very tart and acidic, any fixes?

Tags: cider, techniques, first-time-brewer, taste, acidic

first time cider maker. I recently pressed cooking apples and elderberries into a cider mix, fermented in a bucket for a week with an air gap bung until the bubbles stopped and transferred to bottles with about a teaspoon of sugar in each bottle. I've left the cider do a second fermentation for two weeks and I've opened one to see the results, with being happy that it's carbonated, but the taste is very tart and acidic. Is there a way to fix this? Or is it a case of letting the bottles sit longer to mellow? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yeah letting it condition (letting the cider mellow) will do wonders. The longer you can leave it the better, in my experience. But if you don't want to wait you could back-sweeten, so add a bit of apple juice in your glass.

Answer (score 2):

You have dry cider and this is expected. As Socks^3 mentions, backsweetening is the typical method for taking some of that dry edge off your cider however be mindful that if you backsweeten, you need to stablize the cider first. Otherwise, any yeast in suspension will ferment the additional sugars increasing your ABV while not doing all that much to reduce dryness. Look into potassium metabisulfate and/or potassium sorbate for stablizing.